# laravel, two routes with the same url and different method returns a redirection 301

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have two routes in laravel api routes:

```
Route::get('/user','Api\PassportController@getUser')->name('api.user.show');
Route::put('/user','Api\PassportController@update')->name('api.user.update');
```

But method put it does not work correctly in laravel 5.6 (I send data in body request but laravel resource is empty), so i send **POST** method with **_method = put** param, and laravel redirects to get path using 301 redirect, in my localhost enviroment works fine but in **apache centos server** doesn't work.

When i change the routes like

```
Route::get('/user','Api\PassportController@getUser')->name('api.user.show');
Route::put('/user/update','Api\PassportController@update')->name('api.user.update');
```

Work's fine.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you try to change url order?  
First the `put` url and then the `get` url

Comment: @MaruAmallo yes and doesn't work, 
the last modification I made was to use the name attribute but doesn't work; I think it's a server problem

Comment: Does `php artisan route:list` shows both routes listed in the server? What happens when you send a normal put request without the data in the body (since this problem exists https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457)

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you are not putting the csrf token in you form you can do that by putting `{{ csrf_field() }}`  inside the form .

looking at you code and I'm guessing that you are making an RESTfull API so the best way is to use [larave passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport)

Comment: It's a api route, csrf is not necessary, i use passport and cors to allow all headers.